# Signification de « raduc »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Le terme « raduc » se trouve dans un extrait d'un livre de François Cérésa (Merci qui ? — 2013).

> Dégingandé, sans épaules, veste noire, raduc assorti, on sentait le type intimement tourmenté, capricieux, obtus... Il parlait pas, il fanfaronnait. Il fixait pas, il effleurait. Les mecs de cet acabit, dans le prêt-à-porter

Je ne trouve ce terme dans aucun dictionnaire (TLFi, Wiktionnaire, Larousse, Internaute, Le Robert, …). Il est apparent qu'il s'agit d'un article d'habillement ; pourrait-on décrire ce que ce terme dénomme, et si possible fournir un synonyme qui serait plus usuel et une photographie ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Au vu du champ lexical adopté et du contexte utilisé, je dirais que *raduc* est ici utilisé pour désigner un pantalon porté relativement bas, assorti à la *veste noire*, puisque la personne décrite pourrait porter un ensemble veste-pantalon.

L'expression *raduc* serait ainsi utilisée comme une compression de ***ras-du-cul***, signifiant (dans ce contexte) que le pantalon est porté à la limite de la raie fessière, qui est peut-être même légèrement visible. L'auteur aurait donc choisi une expression réduite afin de ne pas avoir à écrire un terme pouvant paraître "vulgaire".

---

Enfin, dans un contexte plus général, l'expression *ras-du-cul* signifie *de justesse*, *de peu*, *à la limite de*.

*Exemple 1 :* "J'ai eu mon train, mais c'était *ras-du-cul*." signifie que j'ai eu mon train mais que j'étais sur le point de le rater, j'ai pu monter au dernier moment.

*Exemple  2 :* "La voiture a vraiment frôlé le piéton, c'était *ras-du cul* !" où *ras-du-cul* amplifie l'aspect dangereux de l'action, en tant que synonyme de *a frôlé*.

---

Note: On retrouve l'expression ***raduc*** orthographiée ***ras-du-c*** dans l'ouvrage de Kenneth George *L'apocope et l'aphérèse en français familier, populaire et argotique*, 1980, rapportée par [*Bob, dictionnaire d'argot, de français familier et populaire*](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/41399) avec une définition proche mais qui s'applique à une personne plutôt qu'à son pantalon : *Court en jambes*.

Comment: Cette interprétation semble tout à fait plausible. Je ne connaissais pas ce terme de pantalon ras du cul mais effectivement une fois qu'on la connait on trouve facilement l'expression pour désigner des saggings.

Comment: Oh ! Voilà qui semble avoir du sens ! Il serait cependant plaisant de pouvoir consulter une référence ; pas la moindre idée sur un synonyme usuel alors… et « saggings » serait le terme … usuel …

Comment: @None : En fait, c'est assez général : on peut l'utiliser pour des vêtements, mais également dans la vie quotidienne. Un exemple simple : *A : Tu as pu avoir ton train hier ? B : Oui, mais c'était ras-du-cul.* Dans ce cas, ça signifie que la personne a eu son train de peu, avec peu de marge, juste à temps.

Comment: @LPH sagging c'est mon expression mais en fait c'est plus la façon de porter ce qui est désigné dans le commerce par « pantalon en dessous des fesses ».

Comment: En effet, la chose elle-même est assez vulgaire : https://www.google.com/search?q=saggings,image&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=isch&sxsrf=AB5stBiDv4QzATsAW4A3vUSGjQYWsXbTKA:1688731762548&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOl8-GyPz_AhUZVqQEHVi6BH0Q0pQJegQIZxAE&biw=1280&bih=662&dpr=1.5

Comment: @None un exemple exagéré de sagging serait-il un baggy (ou peut-être un synonyme) ? Un baggy est un pantalon très large et ample voire flottant qui, aux alentours des années 2010 était très à la mode chez les adolescents. Il se portait alors très bas de manière à laisser paraître le sous-vêtement (entre la taille et les fesses, sur les fesses, ou sous les fesses).

Comment: Une référence : https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/41399

Comment: @Marck Le baggy c'est surtout dans la largeur, il me semble qu'il ne laisse pas forcément voir le haut du caleçon ou des fesses. Mais c'est pas ma génération tout ça !

Comment: @None Justement c'est la mienne, de génération ! :) Et en effet, le baggy ne semble être que dans la largeur, au temps pour moi !

Comment: @Marck Peut-être serait-il bon d'ajouter le sens plus général à ta réponse? Sinon, on a l'impression qu'il s'agit _seulement_ de vêtements, alors qu'en fait, le sens de _juste/de justesse_ est bien courant maintenant.

Comment: Merci @Frank ! J'ai modifié ma réponse, c'est convenable ?

Comment: @Marck Très bien!

Comment: Mais... si ce n'est dans aucun dictionnaire, tout cela doit être _archi faux_ et personne n'a le droit d'utiliser ce mot! ;-)

Comment: @Frank Mais en plus, **c'est** dans un dictionnaire ([Bob](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/Introduction)). cf. mon commentaire plus haut.

Comment: @jlliagre Comme quoi il y a des erreurs dans les dictionnaires, puisque je le dis! ;-)